# Mockable.io - mock not found for all SOAP mocks

Tags: oracle, soap, soapui

I am making my way through the book "Implementing Oracle Integration Cloud Service" and a few chapters use Mockable.io to mock calls. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get a single SOAP Mock to work. No matter what I try I get "Mock not found." This happens in the browser, if I try to call the mock as an endpoint in SOAPUI and Oracle ICS also returns a "404 not found" when I call the integration that I have the mock wired to and all of the online SOAP clients I've tried return the same result. I have seen other posts that claim Mockable.io works fine for REST mocks, but at least one person could not get any SOAP Mocks to work. Either I'm missing something very basic (likely) or Mockable.io doesn't work consistently with SOAP mocks. Has anyone had success using Mockable.io for SOAP mocks? I am calling the mock with the URL: http://demoXXXXXXX.mockable.io/FlightStatusUpdate (the Xs obscure the demo ID, I am not testing it with Xs, just to be clear). I have not found any resources for Mockable.io online apart from REST resources, I sent them a message and posted on their issues site. I hope the product is still being developed. Any information or guidance would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. No help resources :(